# How do I send an interpolated string on a channel?

Tags: rust

How do I store a variable in a string? I've read the examples, but they are all just `println!()`.

```
//javascript
var url_str = "http://api.weather/city" + city_code + "/get";

//go
urlStr := fmt.Sprintf("http://api.weather/%s/get", cityCode)

// Edit: Rust 
let url_str = format!("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={}", city_code);
```

I am using `tx.send()` and want to send an interpolated string on the channel like this:

```
let url_str = "http://api.weather";
c.send(url_str);
```

but I get an error

```
src/http_get/http_getter.rs:21:17: 21:24 error: `url_str` does not live long enough
src/http_get/http_getter.rs:21         c.send(&url_str);
                                           ^~~~~~~
```

Here is the function that I am trying to implement for constructing the URL:

```
pub fn construct_url(c: &Sender<String>, city_code: &str) {
        let url_str = format!("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={}", city_code);
        println!("{}", url_str);
        c.send(url_str);
}
```

Comment: Hm, `url_str` doesn't seem to be an interpolated string? Could you add some more details, e.g. how `c` is created?

Comment: hi!, I've added the fn that i use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With elided lifetimes and types reinstated, here’s what you have:

```rust
pub fn construct_url<'a, 'b, 'c>(c: &'a Sender<&'b str>, city_code: &'c str) {
    let url_str: String = format!("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={}", city_code);
    println!("{}", url_str);
    c.send(&url_str);
}
```

Bear in mind the distinctions between `String` and `&str`: `&str` is a string slice, a reference to a string that someone else owns; `String` is the owned variety.

`'b` is necessarily at least as long as the entire function body—any string you construct inside the function will not live long enough for `'b`. Therefore your sender will need to send a `String`, not a `&str`.

```rust
pub fn construct_url(c: &Sender<String>, city_code: &str) {
    let url_str = format!("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={}", city_code);
    println!("{}", url_str);
    c.send(url_str);
}
```

Comment: awesome that worked! I'm confused with `String` and `&str` will update my post. thank you!